# How to use custom column names and change structure during unstack?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
op1 = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
'date' : ['1/1/2017','1/2/2017','1/1/2017','1/2/2017','1/11/2017','1/12/2017','1/11/2017','1/12/2017'],
'val' :[5,6,5,11,5,7,16,12],
'item_name':['P','P','F','F','P','P','F','F'],
'val_max':[11,13,15,16,21,22,24,25]
 })
```

[image]

Please note that I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143566/how-to-rename-columns-dynamically-before-unstack-in-pandas) to adapt my code

I would like to transform this to find the `maximum of **val_max** for each subject`.

This is what I tried. Though it works and gives me the output, the structure isn't accurate yet

```
t1 = op1.groupby(['subject_id','item_name'])['val_max'].max().reset_index()
t1.set_index(['subject_id','item_name']).unstack().add_prefix('Max_').rename_axis(None).reset_index()
```

[image]

Instead, I would like to have my output like as shown below

Please note the column names are custom. I don't wish to stick to the `prefix/suffix constraint`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and `axis=1` in [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove columns names:

```
t1 = (op1.groupby(['subject_id','item_name'])['val_max']
         .max()
         .unstack()
         .add_suffix('_max')
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .reset_index())
print (t1)
   subject_id  F_max  P_max
0           1     16     13
1           2     25     22
```

Comment: Is it possible to rename the columns like as shown in output?

Comment: For columns, should I always stick to `_` approach?

Comment: @SSMK - Not sure if understand.

Comment: For example, will I be able to have column names like "Maxpeep" and "Maxfio2"

Comment: @SSMK - yes, then remove `_`