# Convert columns into rows with Pandas for daily data

Tags: pandas

So my dataset CSV looks like

[image]

What I would like is for it to look like

[image]

I am not I should use melt or pivot and in what steps. Thanks

I tried both melt and pivot could not get a clue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove unnecessary column by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and reshape by [`Series.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
        .set_index(['year','dayiyear'])
        .stack()
        .unstack(1)
        .add_prefix('dayiyear')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Comment: year                               dayiyear1 dayiyear2 dayiyear3 dayiyear4 dayiyear5
1961 Unnamed:0                  0           1          2          3             4
1961 precip                          0           0          0          0          0.8

Thanks, very close, this it what is looks like. How should I name the second column since it has no header and how to delete the first row of each year?

Comment: Umm... what's the purpose of that `.rename_axis` jezrael?

Comment: @JonClements - cleaning `dayiyear` column name

Comment: Sorry... not following (early here and still getting coffee down my neck)... how does it clean it?

Comment: @JonClements - reason is `unstack` - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52143579/2901002) - need remove columns name `Country` - in this question need remove `dayiyear`